# Property not found in object type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a simple core data app that uses a tableview and a detail view. I am getting the error message stating that the property managedObjectContext is not found in the object type ChildrenTVC. The problem is that it really is there. I have cleaned the project and deleted the derived data. There must be something else going on.
Here is the code for the object header:

```
@interface ChildrenTVC : CoreDataTableViewController <AddChildTVCDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

and the code for the implementation file:

```
#import "ChildrenTVC.h"


@implementation ChildrenTVC

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
```

Here is the app delegate file where the error registers:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ChildrenTVC.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       ( NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
ChildrenTVC *controller = (ChildrenTVC *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
}
```

The error is at the controller.managedObjectContext. A lot of this is boilerplate code so there is not much to it. I just can't figure out why it is not seeing the property for the managed object context. The property is in the code.

UPdate:

I ended up recreating the file entirely. I am not sure what references are still in place when a file is changed, but something was pointing to the wrong file. I had to empty the trash to get the new file work properly. It seems to work now, though. All the research I did ended up revealing that there are some things that are unexplained in Xcode.

Comment: code seems fine.. Try cleaning your project and if possible restart xcode once again.

Comment: I cleaned the project and restarted Xcode. The error is still there. this is a mystery.

Comment: can type the exact error here?

Comment: Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'ChildrenTVC *' is the exact message that I an receiving.

Comment: This question is very similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169570/objective-c-my-code-doesnt-see-declared-property-property-not-found-in-obj. Maybe just try recreating the file or something?

Comment: I ended up recreating the file. I had to completely eliminate the old file from my computer to get the new file to work. There was some reference that was still active. I can't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved this issue by entirely recreating the header file, but I never really understood why it happened. What I did not understand then were the effects of the changes that I had made to the app. The real problem was an issue in the sequence that the header files were imported. I had changed the #import in two implementation files and that caused the compiler to not read one of the header files. I could see that the code was there, but the compiler could not read the code because it was not importing it. That gave way to the error I was receiving. My solution simply reversed the change that I had made. It would more easily have been solved by simply removing the #import of the view controller header file on the app delegate. I recently tested this and it was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are type casting the navigationController.topViewController but i assume it isn't one in reality. Try this

```
ChildrenTVC *controller = [[ChildrenTVC alloc] init];
NSArray *vcArray = NSArray *vcArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller]:
[self.window.rootViewController setViewControllers:vcArray animated:NO];
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returned another error "assignment to readonly property" and I still have the previous error. There must be something else happening.

Comment: correcte my answer. topViewController is a readonly property. to add viewcontrollers to a `UINavigationController` you have to use `setViewControllers:animated:`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore nevertheless he wants to add his vc to the navigation stack.

Comment: This code has worked in another project. The vc properly adds to the navigation stack. The problem is in passing the managed object to the master view controller from the app delegate. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: I assumed it is a problem with adding the vc to the nav stack cause you declared and synthesized the managedObjectContext correct. is `CoreDataTableViewController` some kind of UI(Table)View sublass? where do you initialize the ChildrenTVC? Do you have a custom init mehthod in your ChildrenTVC?

Answer (score -2):

What happens if you make following changes to ChildrenTVC.h

```
@interface ChildrenTVC : CoreDataTableViewController <AddChildTVCDelegate>
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work. I'm glad that you found a workaround though.