# Objective C - My code doesn't see declared @property - Property not found in object of type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties

I'm new to ObjectiveC and Xcode and I'm having a strange behavior:

This is the Packet class header: Packet.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Packet : NSObject
{
    short index;
    NSData *packetData;
    short totalChunks;
}

@property (nonatomic) short index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *packetData;
@property (nonatomic) short totalChunks;

@end
```

And this is Packet.m

```
#import "Packet.h"

@implementation Packet

@synthesize index;
@synthesize packetData;
@synthesize totalChunks;

-(id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

The problem is i can't use getter and setter although it seems to me that properties are declared and synthesized correctly!

for example:

```
#import "TransferManager.h"


@implementation TransferManager

-(void)sendAckPacket
{
    Packet *packet = [[Packet alloc] init];
    packet.index; //ERROR HERE: Property not found on object of type Packet *

}

@end
```

I know there is no TransferManager.h attached becaues I don't want to write useless stuff, but it imports "Packet.h". Otherwise i should have error during the initialization of *packet.

I'm stuck... Any Help? :)

Comment: 1) What's the difference between `Packet` and `BTPacket`?  2) Try importing the header in "TransferManager.m" rather than "TransferManager.h" and using `@class` in  "TransferManager.h".

Comment: Assuming BTPacket is a subclass of Packet, there is no error on that code. Unless you want the ivars to have protected access, you don't need to declare both the variable and their @property. `packet.index` will throw a warning unless used as a variable, eg: `NSLog(@"%d",packet.index)` but not the warning you posted. If everything fails, delete the Derived Data folder.

Comment: Ok, BTPacket was a typo error :) Thank you for your answerr! I will try your solutions!

Comment: I tried deleting Derived data and moving the import in the .m file of TransferManager but with no luck. I decided to try writing setters and getters by myself but they aren't visible from TransferManager methods. Actually, every method i put in Packet.h is not visible!

Comment: Works for me. Git clone project at https://github.com/j4n0/11169570 and find the differences. It has to be something silly.

Comment: You might also check the preprocessor output. It's possible that `index` has been `#define`d to something else and that expression doesn't look to the compiler like it does to you.

Comment: I ended up copying everything, deleting the class files, recreating them (with the same name!) and pasting back! This shouldn't be a solution but it was the only thing working :/